# C# Regex does not work in Javascript, MVC4, Custom RegularExpressionAttribute, IClientValidatable

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-javascript, unobtrusive-validation

I have a custom regular expression attribute which implements IClientValidate so that I can use it with unobtrustive validate.

When I run it I get the following error in FireBug

> SyntaxError: Invalid quantifier
>   match = new RegExp(params).exec(value);

It obviously does not like the regular expression that is passed to it, it is valid in C#.  I can't seem to work out what I need to do to get it to be valid in JavaScript.

The regex is

`^(?i)([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]?\s?[0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2})$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript regex flavor is extremely limited compared to .NET (C#).  One of the many features it doesn't support is inline modifiers of the form `(?i)regex` or `(?i:regex)`.  However, because you're using the `new RegExp(params)` constructor, you should be able to pass the modifier as the second parameter:

```
"^[A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]?\s?[0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}$",
"i"
```

Comment: Is it possible to have one regex pattern? I only ask this because I am only able to pass one pattern into the MVC ModelClientValidationRegexRule method that I am using.

Comment: The second parameter is just the modifiers.  If you can only pass it one parameter, you'll have to enumerate the lowercase letters explicitly (e.g. `"^[A-PR-UWYZa-pr-uwyz0-9]..."`).

Comment: Thanks, that is what I did it the end.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `(?i)` by `i` modifier:
`var patt=/^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]?\s?[0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2})$/i`

Answer (score 0):

When i run your regex in this : http://regexpal.com/
I get error on this part : `(?i)`

Rexegpal is a JavaScript regular expression tester.
So if you can get it to work here you can then apply it in your code.

Perhaps you have some example string to try with?